# How to convert a currency format (from Excel) into a decimal in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a column in a table called [AMOUNT].  The column contains value uploaded from an excel sheet in the Currency Format (i.e $158.96, ($78.36), $714.98, ($7.73), etc).  How do I convert these values to a decimal so that it no longer has the $ sign or the parentheses (but it should still have a negative sign for the parentheses values)?

What I thought would work is below and it worked on a similar problem but the values were slightly different (it didn't have parentheses for the negative values).

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(MONEY, [AMOUNT])) AS DECIMAL(14,4) AS AMOUNT_V2
```

| Amount | Amount_V2 |
| --- | --- |
| $158.96 | 158.96 |
| ($78.36) | -78.36 |

Comment: This column is in a table on your sql server ? What is the datatype ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Currently, the datatype is varchar and I am trying to format it to decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deal with the parenthesis to result in a negative number - one way would be to use *translate*, such as

```
select Cast(Translate('($78.36)','()','- ') as money)
```

Edit - use nested *replace* if 2016 or prior

```
select Cast(Replace(Replace('($158.45)','(','-'),')','') as money)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am on SQL Server 2016 and it looks like Translate was introduced in 2017 (I should have mentioned that, my bad).  I tried using Replace instead and I am getting 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'.

Comment: Ah ok - in which case use a nested replace - have updated

Comment: If you want to go right to decimal(14,4) just add one more replace for $.

Comment: Yes you can do that of course - the benefit of casting to money is that it will cope with whatever regional currency settings are in place, if that's relevant.

Comment: Thank you! Stu + norlando's extra Replace suggestion was the fix :) Much appreciated!!